# How to force importlib find_loader to use exclusively a specific path?

Tags: python-importlib

I'm trying to re-implement some code based on the `imp` module to to use `importlib` instead. There is a subtle difference between the functions `imp.find_module` and `importlib.find_loader`:

```
# Using imp find_module
>>> import imp
>>> imp.find_module("abc", ["some/path/module.py"])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.3/imp.py", line 220, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_bootstrap._ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named 'abc'

# Using import find_loader
>>> import importlib
>>> loader = importlib.find_loader("abc", ["some/path/module.py"])
>>> loader.path
'/usr/lib64/python3.3/abc.py'
```

It looks like `importlib` is falling back to system libraries, whilst `imp.find_module` is using the `path` parameter in an exclusive way, which ends up raising an exception.

How to force `importlib.find_loader` to use exclusively a specific path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the answer is not to use find_loader but to use instead the importlib.machinery.PathFinder class to lookup for modules in specific paths.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your exact goal is for your code. First off, both calls are wrong as the 'path' argument is meant to be a list of directories, not a specific file.

Second, abc is being returned from the standard library because it is already in sys.modules. Remember, importlib.find_loader() finds the loader for the specified module, so that includes looking in `sys.modules['abc'].__loader__` to skip trying to find it needlessly. Had you specified a module in the standard library (e.g. tokenize) not already imported then importlib.find_loader() would have returned None.

In other words importlib.find_loader() will search for a module in a specific directory when specified in 'path', but you have to be looking for something that has not already been imported.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I actually found the way to do what I wanted. The fact is that importlib is using meta_path rather than path in resolving module names.

Comment: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'find_loader'

Answer (score 1):

I think your usage of both `imp` and `importlib` may be incorrect. The list of paths should be paths to directories, not to specific .py files. You're never going to find abc.py inside module.py, so the import fails.

e.g. I had some custom Fabric pip functions defined in a local `pip.py` file, but I also want to load the official `pip.py` in my site-packages directory. Since I first use importlib to import my custom pip.py, this makes `import pip` load my custom version. To load the module in site-packages, I have to do:

```
from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib
import imp
real_pip = imp.load_module('pip', *imp.find_module('pip', [get_python_lib()]))
```